# NSwag Typescript Proxy custom property annotations/decorators

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, nswag

I am using NSwag.CodeGeneration.Typescript to generate an angular 2 typescript proxy from a .net-core backend and the swagger.json. This works like a charm.

Now I would like to be able to automatically generate custom decorators for my typescript client. Something like this:

The C# class:

```
public class Point {
   // a configurable annotation here
   [configurable]
   private int X
   {
      get; set;
   }
   // a configurable annotation here
   [configurable]
   private int Y
   {
      get; set;
   }        
}
```

The generated typescript proxy...

```
class Point {
private _x: number;
private _y: number;
constructor(data?: any) {
    // set data
}

@configurable(false)
get x() { return this._x; }

@configurable(false)
get y() { return this._y; }
}
```

...with the custom decorator function

```
function configurable(value: boolean) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        descriptor.configurable = value;
    };
}
```

It's my first project with swagger, so I'm not entirely sure where to start. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As of now you can only add extension data to the swagger spec. Generating more attributes with the code gen is not easy to do... Im working on some template improvements so that you can customize tpls. Please create an issue on github so we can tracks this there...

Comment: Thank you @RicoSuter. That sounds great. If anyone needs this, as a work-around we created a metadata service that tells you which properties have which annotations based on the class name. works fine so far.

Comment: Iama was this issue created already? @Rico Suter: Any good news about this feature?

Comment: There are extension points in the templates, eg to provide additional attributes. Please check the njsonschema or nswag wiki